# hibernate one to many annotation foreign key null

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

I have two entities `LR.java` and `LI.java`. One request may have more than one  items on it.

After the execution of this method the lR is always null inside the item table. What I am doing wrong here? Any suggestions

Comment: `public LoanItem() {
    this.loanRequest = new LoanRequest();
}` this should not be done in the constructor... you don't want any empty loanRequest automatically. probably try `GenerationType.AUTO`

Comment: I tried without that also, same error

Comment: you should show the whole code from your test class, because normally you don't want to persist **anything** during a test

Comment: update the test case method.

Comment: post your service class as well. basically post everything that is connected with the test, every class/method, the data runs through until its stored int the database

Comment: update with service and dao methods

Comment: cant find the method: `loanService.createRequest(loanRequest, "skh");`

Comment: update the info. please check now.

Comment: after this line `loanRequest = loanService.createRequest(loanRequest);` print `loanRequest.getRequestNo()` instead of `loanRequest.getProcessInstanceId()`

Comment: I am getting number DQST1700001 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a bidirectional "manytoone" association, so it's develepoer's responsability to keep consistent both sides of the association (that is: loanRequest and loanItems).

You should set the field  loanRequest of the Loanitem entity to point to "right" LoanRequest.
Do you so in the addLoanItem  ?

Beside, unless you really need to "navigate" from one entity to the other and backward I suggest you to use unidirectional association, they are far more manageable and less prone to errors like this.

Anyway, @XtremeBaumer is right, constructor of LoanItem should be empty.